# How to remove or change the "W" icon in "My Sites"?

Tags: php, functions

How can I remove WordPress multi site, or how can I change this icon?

[image: icons]

Comment: You can use this plugin to use a favicon for each site - https://github.com/bueltge/wordpress-multisite-enhancements

Answer (score 1):

Create an admin stylesheet and add to that:

```
.blavatar {
    display: none !important;
}
```